# Serving different urlconfs in a single Django project

Tags: python, django, urlconf

My question is about how to serve multiple urls.py (like urls1.py, urls2.py and so on)   files in a single Django project.

I am using Win7 x64, django 1.4.1, python 2.7.3 and as a server django dev-server tool.
I have decided to use a method which i found by google from

http://effbot.org/zone/django-multihost.htm

I have created a multihost.py file and put in to the django middleware folder:

```
C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\multihost.py
```

With the following code:

```python
from django.conf import settings  
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers  

class MultiHostMiddleware:  
def process_request(self, request):  

    try:  
        host = request.META["HTTP_HOST"]  
        if host[-3:] == ":80":  
            host = host[:-3] # ignore default port number, if present  
        request.urlconf = settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP[host]  
    except KeyError:  
        pass # use default urlconf (settings.ROOT_URLCONF)  

def process_response(self, request, response):  
    if getattr(request, "urlconf", None):  
        patch_vary_headers(response, ('Host',))  
    return response
```

Also in my project setting.py file i have added a mapping dictionary like the link above shows:

```python
# File: settings.py 

HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP = { 

    "mysite1.com": "urls1", 
    #"mysite2.com": "urls2" 

    }
```

---

I did not yet implemented the error handling like described by the link above.

My hosts file includes the follwoing:

```
127.0.0.1    mysite1.com
```

Project structure is the following:

effbot django project folder:

```
 + effbot   
--- settings.py   
--- view.py   
--- wsgi.py   
--- urls.py   
--- urls1.py     

 + objex   
--- models.py   
--- views.py   

 + static   
--- css   
--- images
```

There is no templates folder, because i dont serve html items from files, they are coming from databsse (i doubt that my problem is in this).

Now the problem is: when i go for the adress

```
mysite1.com
```

in my browser with django dev-server launched i get code 301 from the server. And browser shows "cannot display page" message.

Could you please explain me how to use mentioned method? I'm new to django and haven't done any real projects yet. Just have read the docs and launched a couple of sites at home to learn how it works.

I expect that urlconfs will be called in dependance from incoming

```
request.META["HTTP_HOST"]
```

The target is to serve different urlconfs for mysite1.com and mysite2.com
in a single django project.

I think this should to work some how.

Thank you for any feedback.

EDIT:
After some research attempts i found that i plugged my multyhost.py incorrectly in settings.
Fixed now. But the same result still.

Also i found out that my django dev-server tool is not reflecting anyhow that it handles any requests from the browser (IE9) except when i do "http://127.0.0.1".
May be i have to try some production server for my task, like nginx?

Comment: If you unplug `multihost.py` can you get the pages normally, what is the value of `ROOT_URLCONF`? Also if you haven't already, set `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`, and finally you can try to use python debugger by placing line `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` in `multihost.py` so you can stop execution on that and then inspect in greater detail what is happening.

Comment: I can get the page normally even if `multihost.py` is plugged, but the page served is like the default `urls.py` file in use because the django dev server reacts only if i hit it with my local http://127.0.0.1/. Any other declared hostname is considered by windows (i can `ping` to it) but when im trying to use it in browser i get 404 from the browser (not from django). `ROOT_URLCONF = 'effbot.urls.py'`. `DEBUG` in the `settings.py` is set to true from the start of the project, i didn't change it yet. Good advice about `set_trace`, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ROOT_URLCONF` should be `effbot.urls` without `.py`as you can see in the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf).

Also, `HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP` should reflect the `ROOT_URLCONF` so add `effbot. like this:

```
HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP = { 
    "mysite1.com": "effbot.urls1", 
    #"mysite2.com": "effbot.urls2" 
}
```

One more thing, please try with another browser (Chrome, Firefox), sometimes I had problems accessing dev server with IE.

Comment: I have tried chrome, but the result is the same as IE9. Thx for pointing on `HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP` could be the reason of my fail here (or one of reasons). Will try.

Comment: I made some more attepmts to resolve it. I fixed the custom urls1.py plugging to the dict. Then was nothing new. But i changed a "HTTP_HOST" to a "SERVER_NAME" in multihost.py and django actually made an attempt to take a custom urls1.py. Our DB is not online now so i can't do any good testing atm. I will provide more exact answer in a couple of days.

Comment: For testing I recommend quick setup of local sqllite database, Just modify [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup) and sync. Good luck.

Comment: Finally i managed to get back to this problem again. Method described in the initial post works fine. Url configs swap is working. All a did is migrated to freeBSD and used real webserver (Nginx) with WSGI correclty configured.